# How to attain opacity in a shape drawn in a layer of UIView that is a subView of a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have an image presented in a `UIImageView` which takes up the entire view of the `UIViewController`.  I would like to draw a `circle(fill: yellow)` in the layer of a subview(UIView) of this `UIImageView`.  My problem is the following, how do I make the opacity of this yellow circle such that it can see through to the background image (e.g opacity 0.2).  I have tried the following without success.  All I get is a solid yellow circle on top of the background image.  I need this yellow circle to be in the layer of the subView as described, rather than in a layer of the `UIImageView`.

```
let dotSize: CGFloat = 30
var fourthDotView: UIView?
@IBOutlet weak var imgPreViewOutlet: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fourthDotView = UIView.init()
    fourthDotView?.frame = CGRect.init(x: fourthOrigin.x, y: fourthOrigin.y, width: dotSize, height: dotSize)

    drawFourthDot()
    imgPreViewOutlet.addSubview(fourthDotView!)

}



// DRAW YELLOW CIRCLE
func drawFourthDot() -> Void {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer.init()
    layer.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: fourthDotView!.bounds, cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.init(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
    fourthDotView?.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting `layer.opacity`?

Comment: yeah that's it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting the opacity, you should use the [`opacity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410933-opacity) property.

```
layer.opacity = 0.20
```